# How do I jump back to the (old) instruction pointer if I edit the instruction pointer of a thread?

Tags: c#, assembly, 64-bit, pinvoke, x86-64

I am attempting to edit the instruction pointer of a thread to get it to call some assembled x64 assembly before jumping back to the old instruction pointer and continue as per normal. The program that I am doing this to crashes after I resume the thread which I assume indicates that it isn't jumping back to the old instruction pointer.

Currently, I am trying the following

**Get the the handle of the thread**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadPrivileges dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, IntPtr dwThreadId);

public enum ThreadPrivileges
{
    SuspendResume = 0x02,
    GetContext = 0x08,
    SetContext = 0x010,
    AllAccess = SuspendResume | GetContext | SetContext
}

var threadId = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].Threads[0].Id;

var threadHandle = OpenThread(ThreadPrivileges.AllAccess, false, (IntPtr)threadId);
```

**Suspend the thread**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);

SuspendThread(threadHandle);
```

**Get the context of the thread**

The structure of Context64 and ContextFlags can be found at this [link](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetThreadContext)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetThreadContext(IntPtr hThread, ref Context64 lpContext);

var context = new Context64() { ContextFlags = ContextFlags.ContextFull };
GetThreadContext(threadHandle, ref context);
```

**Attempt to write the old instruction pointer to the stack**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

context.Rsp -= sizeof(ulong); // Allocate 8 bytes on the stack

WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, (IntPtr)context.Rsp, BitConverter.GetBytes(context.Rip), sizeof(ulong), 0);
```

**Overwrite the instruction pointer**

```
context.Rip = (ulong)myAssemblyPointer;
```

**Set the thread context to the edited context**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetThreadContext(IntPtr hThread, ref Context64 lpContext);

SetThreadContext(threadHandle, ref context);
```

**Finally resume the thread**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

ResumeThread(threadHandle);
```

I'm not sure if this has any relevance but the assembly I am using is the following

```
PUSHFQ
PUSH rax
PUSH rbx
PUSH rcx
PUSH rdx
PUSH r8
PUSH r9
PUSH r10
PUSH r11

sub RSP, 0x28
movabs RCX, 0x0000000000000000  ; Pointer 1
movabs RAX, 0x0000000000000000  ; Pointer 2
call RAX
add RSP, 0x28

POP r11
POP r10
POP r9
POP r8
POP rdx
POP rcx
POP rbx
POP rax
POPFQ

ret
```

I've tried to exclude as much code (error checking and cleaning up after) as I can to keep this post short but all of my error checking seem to indicate that the pinvoke methods are working as intended. My main concern is when I attempt to write the old instruction pointer to the stack. Whilst `WriteProcessMemory` doesn't fail, I have a feeling that I am doing this incorrectly. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me whether I am writing the old instruction pointer to the stack correctly and if not, how I could accomplish it.

Please let me know if you want me to provide any additional information, for example, the `processHandle` or `myAssemblyPointer` variables.

Comment: The only possible problem I can see is that you are not ensuring stack pointer alignment for your hook function. It might not matter. Use a debugger to see where the crash is.

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes(context.Rip), sizeof(ulong)` - this is wrong too for x64 - you write only 4 bytes of return address instead 8 bytes. of course you need change asm code for force align rsp to multiple16 bytes. also you not need get `CONTEXT_FULL`, the `CONTEXT_CONTROL` is enough. and main - if thread say wait inside system call (usually this and happens) your code will execute only after thread exit from wait state

Comment: some like `push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
and rsp,not 0Fh
sub RSP, 20h
/**/
mov rsp,rbp
pop rbp` and `&context.Rip, sizeof(context.Rip)`

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments:

You are reading only 4 bytes, you need to read 8 because it's a x64 process and that is the size required for a memory address pointer.  A long is only 4 bytes, you need to use long long.

Comment: He’s not overwriting any instructions, as you would if you’re patching a binary. He’s dynamically pushing the current RIP on the stack and force loading another value into RIP. When his thunk returns, it should return to the point where execution was interrupted.

Comment: Also he needs to make sure the stack pointer is properly aligned, as mentioned by Jester. In fact, depending on what is known about the process being hooked, it’s possible that RSP may not point to valid stack space. (That part may not be worth worrying about.)